# categories casecading wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i found an awesome code  for casecading [here](http://pastebin.com/5HpyYFPN)

my question is : how to pass wordpress categories and custom taxonomy to this javascript
so i can select the parent then i'll see his children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) method to get the categories and recursively parse them using php.

I would do it like this: get_categories('parent=0') returns all top level categories loop trough them and parse each of the child categories using get_categories('parent=' . $parentId) or get_categories('child_of=' . $nodeId). While looping count the depth of the deepest level of categories and fill the javascript nLists variable with it.

Comment: you are right , but i couldn't get the values (cat's ids) so i can insert them into the database , i have got their values as strings (cats_names) but i am not sure if can insert them into DB by their names.(i'll try to do that) thank you

Comment: You don't need specific cat id's. `get_categories('parent=0')` returns all the top level categories, loop through them 

like this: 

`$topCategories=  get_categories('parent=0'); 
  foreach ($topCategories as $topCategory) {
   echo $topCategory->cat_ID; // <- this is the id of the category 1 level below the top category
  }`

Like this you'll dynamically browse through them without ever having to set or know an id yourself